# Query lots of history records in database or other store

Tags: sql-server, caching, redis, bigdata

I have a historical data table like (Date,ItemId,Price). Normally around 60,000 records will be inserted into the table. Now, the table record amount is around 3 millions. And our query is something like select 2000 products in 3 months which is very slow in present. I already make some indexes for it , but I still want more better performance.

For this situation, how can I do can make the query faster? Table partitioning or Caching ?

Thanks

Comment: You should add more details, like what is "very slow" and what is the performance requirement Adding example query, table & index structure and query plan is needed to analyse if there's something that can be improved in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the the version of SQL Server you are using? Partitioning only works with Enterprise edition.

To improve performance, you may make use of temporary tables, i.e. create temporary table on a subset (rows and columns) of data which you require. Temporary table would be smaller than original table, further they can be indexed also if required. This subset of data stored in temp tables can also be cached thereby increasing performance.